# Jersey client POST request body size limit

Tags: java, jersey, http-post, httpclient

I have a tehnical document from our clientsays that their server will accept POST request with post body up to 2.5MB. 
I wrote a batch processor that takes some data and generates chunks of JSON out of it with predetermined size limit. Then it posts them in sequence to server using some retry logic etc..

If I set the size limit under 2 000 000 bytes it works fine.
If I set it 2 400 000 bytes the bach processor throws following stack.
(It was hard to tell if they meant decimal or binary “MB”s so I tried to play it safe and also leave a large margin for errors)

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
    at ***************.BatchProcessor.sendBatchRequest(BatchProcessor.java:55)
```

Is there some kind of a limit to the size a jersey client POST body can have? Can I change it?
It seems to be the problem on the sending side.

I sent the batch to a simple test server that I implemented using.

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
```

Maybe it has somekind of limits.
But there were nothing suspicious going on there and the error message seems to impliacate the client.
Any ideas?